# BSOD when running Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: windows-8, bsod, boot-camp

Each time I run the Windows Phone 8 emulator in Visual Studio 2012, I get a BSOD with the message `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`.

I cannot seem to locate where this logged so I can see which device is causing the error.

Also, it should be noted I am running Windows 8.1 on a Macbook Air using Bootcamp.  The Bootcamp drivers I tried to install after the fact, but kept getting `Boot Camp requires that your machine is running Windows 7` yet the drivers [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720) state they support Windows 8.1

Comment: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA is usually a driver error (or hardware failure).  What version of boot Camp are you using?  Also see [Where does Windows 8 store user-mode crash minidumps?](http://superuser.com/questions/553140/where-does-windows-8-store-user-mode-crash-minidumps)

Comment: Confirm your hardware is listed in the article you linked to.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to the desktop, zip it and upload the zip (cloud service) and post a link here.

Comment: where are the dumps?